# C# Иерархическая структура и Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем здравствуйте! Пишу простенькую программку для своего производства. C# изучаю довольно недавно и столкнулся с проблемой. Опишу цель и задачи, которые необходимо решить:

Программа на WinForms, доступ к БД MS SQL - Entity Framework 6.0. К примеру, фактически имеется множество деталей:
деталь1, деталь2, деталь3 ... деталь150, у всех деталей есть поля:

<деталь1>

- Наименование
- Номер чертежа
- Операция
  и т.п.
  Каждая деталь состоит из списка деталей, но каких-то деталей должно быть некоторое кол-во:
  {деталь3-3шт.,
  деталь15-1шт.,
  деталь45-450шт.}
  Каждая из этих деталей тоже  в свою очередь состоит из каких-то деталей.
  Как бы казалось, что структура - простая иерархия, но только ровно до того момента, пока детали не пересекаются, например:
  Есть три детали - деталь1, деталь2 и деталь3:

<деталь1>

- наименование
- №чертежа
- Состав: деталь4-1шт., деталь5-1шт., деталь6-35шт., деталь7-450шт.

<деталь2>

- наименование
  -№чертежа
- Состав: деталь8-1шт., деталь5-3шт., деталь7-300шт.

Тут как бы нет проблем и всё работает нормально и понятно, объекты сохраняются в БД без проблем. Но если в иерархию вступают ниже приведенная деталь, то нифига не получается:

<деталь3>

- наименование
- №чертежа
- Состав: деталь9-1шт., **деталь1**-1шт., **деталь2**-10шт.

И когда я пытаюсь сохранить сие чудо - пишет, что присутствуют множественные ссылки. И не пойму как реализовать структуру.

Теперь к задаче: мне необходимо в БД сохранить шаблон по которому будут создаваться заказы и отслеживаться их выполнение. К примеру: сначала в БД сохраняются шаблоны Деталей с их структурой, затем мне приходит заказ на "Деталь3" - я должен создать объекты по этому шаблону со структурой:
<Деталь3>

- Наименование: Деталь №3
- №Чертежа: №1234
- Состав:
  <Деталь8> {нужно - 1, сделано - 0}
  <Деталь5> {нужно - 3, сделано - 0}
  - Наименование
  - №чертежа
  - Состав: деталь4 {нужно - 1, сделано - 0}
  деталь5 {нужно - 1, сделано - 0}
  ....
  <Деталь2> {нужно - 10, сделано - 0}
  - Наименование
  - №чертежа
  - Состав: деталь4 {нужно - 1, сделано - 0}
  деталь5 {нужно - 1, сделано - 0}
  ....

Далее я изменяю кол-во изготовленных деталей с низа  дерева до конечного  изготовления детали3. Я уже битый месяц перебираю различные варианты реализации этой задачи, но не могу придумать структуру этих объектов. Если не сложно - помогите хотя бы направить на мысль в каком направлении смотреть..

В идеале - есть множество структур, состоящих из экземпляров класса Р.  в каждой структуре есть дочерние экземпляры, в которых есть ещё дочерние и так сколько угодно. Но любой из экземпляров может быть и дочерним элементом совсем другой структуры. Я работаю с EntityFramework 6. В решении всё работает как положено, но при отправке объекта в БД SQL ругается на множественные ссылки, типа на один объект не могут ссылаться несколько объектов. Плюс ко всему каждый объект Р может иметь различные варианты исполнения (прим. Р2).

Comment: Чтобы правильно работала иерархическая структура, нужно идти с верху в низ, иначе будут присутствувать множественные ссылки. Получается что деталь три ссылается на деталь один, так нельзя делать, а если и можно то не с такой структурой БД!

Comment: как мне кажется вам стоит изменить вопрос, в данном случае Ваш вопрос больше относится к структуре(схеме) бд, если будет ответ который Вас устроит, Вам всего лишь останется перенести это в entity framework. Приложите схему существующей бд(в виде картинки), опишите что хочется

Comment: Укажите используемую СУБД.

Comment: По-моему, ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь указать связь на _конкретную_ деталь. А нужна связь на _тип_ детали. Например, гайка м5. Их имеется миллион штук. Вряд ли важна связь с конкретной гайкой №1234. Скорее просто нужно указать именно 'м5'.

Answer (score 0):

Существует несколько способов хранения иерархий в реляционных СУБД. Здесь описаны четыре основных: [Иерархические структуры и деревья в SQL](https://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032). Кроме того, возможны их комбинации.

У каждого из способов есть достоинства и недостатки. Следует определить, какие операции чаще всего будут нужны в нашем приложении и выбрать наиболее подходящий способ.

Потом нужно прикинуть, а подходит ли этот способ под нашу СУБД? В частности, для работы со списками смежности (adjacency list) необходимо, чтобы СУБД умела делать рекурсивные запросы в CTE. При использовании подмножеств необходимы триггеры для поддержания ссылочной целостности. Бывают некоторые СУБД, которые не имеют то или другое.

Далее смотрим на возможности выбранной СУБД. В некоторых есть встроенные средства для работы с иерархическими структурами. Например, в Sql Server есть тип [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16), а в PostgreSQL есть расширение ltree. Оба являются реализаций матиреализованного пути. Этот способ, возможно, окажется не идеальным именно для нашего случая, но т. к. он встроен в СУБД, то наверняка окажется быстрым и более удобным для использования.

Далее, решаем, с помощью чего будем работать с базой данных. При использовании сырых SQL-запросов нам доступны все возможности. Но если берём ORM, то она ограничивает нас. И сперва следует поискать, может ли эта ORM на выбранной СУБД использовать тот или иной способ работы с иерархиями. Вот, например, нашлась такая статья: [Hierarchy in the Entity Framework 6 with the hierarchyid type](https://kariera.future-processing.pl/blog/hierarchy-in-the-entity-framework-6-with-the-hierarchyid-type/).